# Redis performance: hIncrByFloat function or custom Lua script ？

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis

let's say I have hash data stored in redis:

```
{"fee":0.11,"name":"scott"}
```

now I want to add some value to the field 'fee', should I use the hIncrByFloat command or , write a Lua script to implement that? please advice from the performance view, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `HINCRBYFLOAT`.

Core commands are more performant than Lua scripts in (probably) every scenario. Use Lua to compose flows that consist of core commands and server-side logic, but not to replace a single core command.

You can, and should, test performance yourself - `redis-benchmark` can be used for that.